# Manually resolve promise for getPromiseFinishAllItems

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, reportportal

I'm using a combination of protractor, selenium, jasmine and report portal for automated testing. The tests all run fine but when it comes to the last test it always hangs and it eventually fails, looking into it, it seems to come down to what is used in the afterAll function in my protractor.conf.js file.

```
jasmineEnv.afterAll(async (done) => {
    await agent.getPromiseFinishAllItems(agent.tempLaunchId);

    done();
});
```

Now the function it calls comes from the node modules reportportal-agent.js :

```
getPromiseFinishAllItems(launchTempId){
    return this.client.getPromiseFinishAllItems(launchTempId)
}
```

I've noticed that written above this function is the comment

```
/*
 * This method is used for frameworks as Jasmine and other. There is problems when
 * it doesn't wait for promise resolve and stop the process. So it better to call
 * this method at the spec's function as @afterAll() and manually resolve this promise.
 *
 * @return a promise
 */
```

I'm wondering is there a solution for how to properly resolve this promise? I have tried looking online but not found anything of any significance

EDIT -

protractor.conf.js

```
const ReportportalAgent = require('agent-js-jasmine');
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const suiteSettings = require('./suiteSettings');
const settings = require('./settings');
const logger = require('./tests/helpers/logger');

// This is a temporary solution because we have issues if instances=nodes. For now balance between nodes and instances that instances < 3
const nodeReduceCount = 5;
let isBrowserOpen = false;

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: settings.seleniumHubHost,
    capabilities: {
        'shardTestFiles': true,
        'maxInstances': Math.max(settings.countOfStreams - nodeReduceCount, 1),
        'browserName': settings.browser,
        'loggingPrefs': {
            performance: 'INFO',
        },
        'moz:firefoxOptions': getFirefoxOptions(),
        'goog:chromeOptions': getChromeOptions(),
    },
    suites: [
        suiteSettings.suite,
    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: settings.jasmineTimeout,
        isVerbose: false,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        realtimeFailure: false,
    },
    onPrepare: async () => {
        const jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        const capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
        const config = await browser.getProcessedConfig();

        global.consoleReporter = [];

        console.log(capabilities);

        if (!settings.useReportPortal) {
            registerReporter(jasmineEnv);
        } else {
            registerConsoleReporter(jasmineEnv);
        }

        jasmineEnv.beforeEach(async () => {
            jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = settings.jasmineTimeout;

            const criticalCheck = String(config.specs);

            if (criticalCheck.includes('critical')) {
                process.env.RUN_WITH_SERVICE_WORKER = 'true';
            } else {
                process.env.RUN_WITH_SERVICE_WORKER = '';
            }

            if (isBrowserOpen) {
                browser.restart();
            }

            await browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(settings.viewPort.width, settings.viewPort.height);

            isBrowserOpen = true;

            await logger.logMessage(`Opening Link ${settings.newPlanUrl()}`);

            await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
            await browser.get(settings.newPlanUrl());
        });
    },
};

function registerReporter(jasmineEnv) {
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true,
        },
    }));

    const config = {
        id: browser.params.id,
        ...settings.reportPortal,
    };
    const agent = new ReportportalAgent(config);
    const reporter = agent.getJasmineReporter();

    jasmineEnv.afterAll(async (done) => {
        await agent.getPromiseFinishAllItems(agent.tempLaunchId);

        done();
    });

    global.reporter = reporter;
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(reporter);

    return agent;
}

function registerConsoleReporter(jasmineEnv) {
    jasmineEnv.afterEach(async () => {
        await browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
            const testSuite = settings.currentSuite;
            const date = new Date();
            const currentDay = `(Time-${date.getHours()}-${date.getMinutes()}-${date.getSeconds()})`;
            logger.writeScreenShot(png, `screenshots/${currentDay}_${testSuite}.png`);
        });
    });
    jasmineEnv.afterAll(async () => {
        await console.log('\n---------------------------------');
        await console.log('Test Results');
        await global.consoleReporter.forEach((testResult) => {
            console.log(testResult);
        });
        await console.log('---------------------------------');
    });
}

function getFirefoxOptions() {
    const options = {};

    if (settings.headless) {
        options.args = ['--headless'];
    }

    return options;
}

function getChromeOptions() {
    const options = {
        args: [
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-extensions',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-infobars',
        ],
    };

    if (settings.headless) {
        options.args.push('--headless');

        options.perfLoggingPrefs = {
            enableNetwork: true,
        };
    }

    return options;
}
```

Edit:

So the error I had before was due to adding:

agent.getExitPromise.

But I've noticed after removing that and running my test suite again to see if jenkins would log anything useful when it comes to the test that gets interrupted, it says:

```
13:43:26  Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
13:43:26  ...Sending interrupt signal to process
13:43:31  npm ERR! path /app
13:43:31  npm ERR! command failed
13:43:31  npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
13:43:31  npm ERR! command sh -c node generateTests.js && node start.js
```

does anyone have any idea what the cause of this could be?

Comment: something doesn't sound right. In order to resolve Promise you need to use `await` (or `then()`, but don't overcomplicate your life). Once you called `await promise()` you don't need to do anything else. if something doesn't work, look somewhere else

Comment: and one more. For completing all promises before exiting protractor, this is what `onComplete` is there for. For example, I have a reporter which updates test cases statuses in Jira by sending API requests. Since all requests are promises, I just queued them up, and instruct onComplete to wait until all are resolve and only then to exit

Comment: the bottom line is - either what you think is the problem is not actually the cause, or if it causes such behavior, your implementation (overall approach) is wrong

Comment: Okay, that is making more sense, I was wondering why the promise wasn't resolving as like you said, you use await or then. I have actually taking over from someone else who set this up. I will have a look more into onComplete, did not know this was a thing so thanks for that!

Comment: @iross12 also I never use `done()` I think it's legacy thing

Comment: I've edited the question to include my protractor.conf.js file, is there anything you'd say doesn't look right? If you don't mind having a look that is

Comment: wow pretty neat code! A few things I noticed on the surface are - instead of `seleniumAddress` explore more about `directConnect` (but this will comes at a cost of changing how you run tests), as I said before `done` function seems to be redundant these days, not sure how your `capabilities` work if you mention firefox - to my knowledge it should have been `multipleCapabilities` but I only worked with chrome, so I may not know something. For the rest, it'd require deeper exploration of your entire code to provide a feedback

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll definitely look at replacing the done function and look more into directConnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found out what the issue was, we had files that were in the incorrect directory. That was it, once these were moved to the correct place, the issue stopped happening and the last test no longer gets hung up. So for anyone else that comes across this issue, this is something to check

Comment: @Iross12 can you help me which directory the tests should present? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So after comments with Sergey which helped massively. I realised I was looking in the wrong area and tried to think more of what is happening. Looking at the test runs I noticed that the last test was cut off so I figured I must be closing the connection somewhere before the last test has a chance to finish.

What I've done, which seems to work is do:

```
jasmineEnv.afterAll(async (done) => {
    await agent.getPromiseFinishAllItems(agent.tempLaunchId);

    await agent.getExitPromise();

    done();
});
```

Getting the exit promise appears to have solved the issue

Comment: Okay well turns this only worked for 1 run, went back to having the last test cut off again

Comment: yeah, that seems like a race condition. The worst thing that you can ever debug